# Accessing Simple Array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am literally exhausted right now and failing to access simplest array values in javascript,
Okay, i have printed `console.log(dataArray)`

Console Output:

```
[]
    account_level : "-"
    address : "-"
    atm_issued : "-"
    avatar : "-"
    branch : "-"
    cnic : "-"
```

[image]

This is what i am trying to access by this:

```
console.log(dataArray['cnic'])
```

By this

```
console.log(dataArray.cnic)
```

And by this

```
console.log(dataArray[cnic])
```

And if i do

```
console.log(dataArray.cnic)
```

It prints `undefined`

```
console.log(dataArray.length, dataArray instanceof Array, dataArray instanceof Object);
```

Output of above:

> 0 true true

How do I access this property?

Comment: you access an array by its index. Your approach above is how you would retrieve the values from an array

Comment: What you have provided is not an array in Javascript. It is an object. Objects store their values behind string indexes, arrays use numeric indexes.

Comment: What you mean sir?

Comment: Buddy, take a deep breath and try to elaborate on what you are trying to do and failing so we can help you.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: Noman please add to your question the output of `console.log(dataArray.length, dataArray instanceof Array, dataArray instanceof Object);`

Comment: yup, the `[]` in the log is a bit confusing

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Done.

Comment: While you can add arbitrary properties to an array, it’s rather unconventional, which is why you get so many confused comments and answers. How is the data actually added to the array and when/how aren’t you trying to access it? I think you’re accesing the array **before** the properties have been added.

Comment: exactly. just ignore the answers so far. can you show how and when the array is defined and how and when youre trying to access the values?

Comment: Then why it's printing in console? that means values are added. @FelixKling

Comment: @NomanAli when you have asynchronous magic happen this could be a possible origin of your confusion :)

Comment: This only means that the properties exist  *at the time you expanded the array in the console*, not at the time you are logging the array. The order of operations could very well be: 1. Log array. 2. Log property. 3. Add property. 4. Inspect array in console.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have resolved this issue, `i was rendering components before array being populated`. but why it was being printed in console. That's still a confusion.

Comment: show the whole code and we can lift the mystery!

Comment: Noman if you don't mind also printing the output of `console.log(dataArray.__proto__);`.

Comment: Because when inspecting an object in the console it is evaluated when you expand it. By that time it may have changed. That is what the little blue i is telling you.

Comment: @FelixKling sure? when you log an object, it should the object state at that point, shouldnt it?

Comment: @alex: 110% sure.

Comment: @FelixKling youre right, wow. i didnt know that and too me this makes absolutely no sense :D

Comment: @NomanAli Is my answer satisfying your needs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a pain, but i was using firebase, and accessing properties before they were being populated. So first i have let them be populated then access them.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you can't define an `array` like this beacause the [syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) is not compatible.

I suggest you instead of this to use [OBJECT SYNTAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) as the following code snippet shows:

```js
var obj={
 account_level : "DATA",
    address : "-",
    atm_issued : "-",
    avatar : "-",
    branch : "-",
    cnic : "-"
};

console.log(obj.account_level);
```

---

You can Also fill the *object* dynamically like this:

```js
var obj={};

obj["address"] = "DATA1";
obj["atm_issued"] = "DATA2";
obj["avatar"] = "DATA3";
obj["branch"] = "DATA4";
obj["cnic"] = "DATA5";

console.log(obj.cnic);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: That is not an array. It is an object. The OP's confusion probably stemmed from this misunderstanding.

Comment: @Lix can you take a look to my edit please & give me your feedback ?

Comment: its not json syntax. its object syntax.

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi - good edits! Definitely an improvement from your first version :)

Comment: *"In your case you can't define an array like this"* One can easily do `var arr = []; arr.cnic = 'foo';`. The OP *should* not use an array for their purposes, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are using is how you would access an object.

```js
let object = {
  account_level: "-"
  address: "-"
  atm_issued: "-"
  avatar: "-"
  branch: "-"
  cnic: "-"
};

console.log(object.cnic);
```

To access an array you use its index.

```js
let array = ['Chelsea', 'Liverpool', 'Arsenal'];

console.log(array[0]);
```

Comment: *"The syntax you are using is how you would access an object."* Well, arrays **are** objects. If an array has a property `cnic`, then using `array.cnic` will work perfectly fine. After all,  accessing `array.length` works fine too.

Comment: @FelixKling you are correct that arrays are objects. What I don't understand is the second point `If an array has a property cnic, then using array.cnic`... in the example I provide if I do `array.Chelsea` ir returns undefined. How can an array have a property? Im confused :-S

Comment: `var arr = []; arr.Chelsea = 'foo';`. In *your example*, `array` does *not* have a `Chelsea` property, it has the string value `'Chelsea'` as one of it's elements. That's different.

Comment: @FelixKling weird, i have never seen that before. Is that a new thing with JS, or has it been around for a long time? Do you have any link where I could read more about this

Comment: It's been around for as long as arrays have been around. It's just not a common thing to do. I don't know of any specific resource that covers this in depth. Usually it is just explained with the fact that arrays are objects. And objects can have arbitrary properties.

Answer (score 1):

JS arrays always have integers as index. If your key is a text, that means it is an object.

you can access an object these ways

```
var a = {key1 : "value1", key2 : "value2"};

//METHOD 1
console.log(a.key1);

//METHOD 2
console.log(a['key1']);
```

This is array

```
var a = ["value1","value2"];
console.log(a[0]);
```

Comment: Don’t use the term JSON when talking about JavaScript objects. It’s wrong and confusing.

Comment: agree. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

What you have specify is something like `object` not an `array`. In case of `object` the `key:value` pair are separated by `,` which is missing in your format. So the final format is like:

```js
var obj = { "account_level" : "-",
    "address" : "-",
    "atm_issued" : "-",
    "avatar" : "-",
    "branch" : "-",
    "cnic" : "-" };
    
console.log(obj.cnic);
```

Comment: he is printing the log, not defining so the format does not apply. and arrays are objects, also.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something weird is going on with the way your array/object is being filled, please try creating a new one from it as follows :

```
dataArray = Object.assign({}, dataArray);
console.log(console.log(dataArray.cnic));
```

Comment: How would that help? If `dataArray` doesn't have such a property, how does copying a non-existing property make it appear?

Comment: But it exists from what the console log is showing.

Comment: See [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429421/accessing-simple-array-values-in-javascript/46429973?noredirect=1#comment79816495_4642942). If it's not possible to access the property with `dataArray.cnic`, then won't be possible to access it after copying it.

Comment: I do not know the internal workings of `Object.assign` but my reasoning was that maybe it would resolve this kind of weird glitch he is facing. Ok sure he cannot access the property directly but the console still sees it.

Comment: As I said in the comment, that's most likely because at the time they expand the value in the console, it will have those properties. At that time they could access them via `dataArray.cnic` as well. Try this in the console: `var obj1 = {}; console.log(obj1); var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1); obj1.foo = 42; console.log(obj2);`. Notice how expanding `obj1` shows the property (even though it could not have possibly existed at the time we logged the object) and `obj2` does not.

Comment: Oh good catch, let's confirm that by suggesting he pastes the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray));`. I'll delete this answer if that is confirmed.

Comment: The problem with `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray));` is that it wouldn't show arbitrary properties anyway. `JSON.stringify(array)` only takes true array elements into consideration, not arbitrary properties: `var arr = []; arr.foo = 42; console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));`. So that wouldn't help us much. But `dataArray.hasOwnProperty('cnic')` might suffice.

Comment: I am not following, if the array is empty at the beginning, it will be confirmed by the output of the console statement I provided, if we want to make sure that no other stuff is present, I believe this will help : `console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, dataArray)));`